# Can I change the twitter widget search query dynamclly without stating it in the widget settings page?

Tags: twitter

I want to embed a twitter widget inside my web-app Using [the widget API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines).

I want to know if I can change the query string inside the embed code without the need to actually change it on the widget settings page. This way I can use the same widget for multiple search queries according to the topic of the page the user is currently at, without the need to create a new widget for each one.

As anyone tried something like this?

Does this on any way violate the terms of service of Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to twitter, you can not :(

https://twittercommunity.com/t/change-search-query-from-program/20435